# How to rename a created snapshot by adding tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, snapshot

I want to create a snapshot then add tags to it. This is my code:

```
snapshot=ec2client.create_snapshot(VolumeId=volume_id,Description=description)
print snapshot['Tags']['Key']
```

I know that `snapshot` is a `dictionnary` and will have this syntax:

```
{
    'SnapshotId': 'string',
    'VolumeId': 'string',
    'State': 'pending'|'completed'|'error',
    'StateMessage': 'string',
    'StartTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'Progress': 'string',
    'OwnerId': 'string',
    'Description': 'string',
    'VolumeSize': 123,
    'OwnerAlias': 'string',
    'Tags': [
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ],
    'Encrypted': True|False,
    'KmsKeyId': 'string',
    'DataEncryptionKeyId': 'string'
}
```

When I do like this :

```
snapshot.add_tags({'foo': 'bar'})
```

I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add_tags'`
I'm wondering how to access the key and values of tags and change them ?
Which function to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add or overwrite tags you have to use **createTags** API/function.

We are not allowed to add tags while creating snapshots. Please use separate API/Function to add the tags to the snapshots.

Hope this helps, Thanks

Comment: I get this error : ` AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'createTags'

Comment: please follow the document: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags

Comment: A big thanks to you!! that's what I was looking for. successful operation